# How do I use std::chrono to extract time units out of epoch time?

Tags: c++, epoch, c++-chrono

I get the epoch time in `ms` from my API and would like to extract the year, month, etc. from it (also compare two dates, add hours/days/months, etc.).

I have watched Howard Hinnant ["A chrono Tutorial"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M&pp=ygUVaG93YXJkIGhpbm5hbnQgY2hyb25v) and tried [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day), but I can't quite get it to work.

Here is all I have so far:

```cpp
enum class DatePrecision { YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, MILLI };
long long et = 1693322440062;
std::chrono::milliseconds ms{ et };
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> tp(ms);

int getTimeUnit(const std::chrono::time_point tp, const DatePrecision dp) { 
  /* .?. */ 
}
```

Where do I go from here? `tp` only offers me `time_since_epoch` as a function on it and as I said, I can't get the example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day) to work, especially when using `utc_time` instead of `system_time`. Extracting yeah/month/day would be a great start, but I would prefer

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using C++20 with a std::lib that has implemented all of the C++20 chrono bits such as MSVC 19.x?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Yes, I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with MSVC 19.x with C++20. I now realize that I was not precise in my OP: The code from cppreference does compile, what I meant was that I just didn't know how to adapt it for what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is pretty easy to do, but I don't recommend it.  The reason I don't recommend it is that it is best to stay *within* the chrono type system so that the compiler can help you find any logic errors at compile-time.  Returning these values as an `int` erases the type safety that chrono provides you.

Ok, enough with the lecture.  Here's how you can do it in C++20 (assuming your vendor has implemented all of the chrono parts of C++20):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

enum class DatePrecision { YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, MILLI };

int
getTimeUnit(const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp, const DatePrecision dp)
{ 
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto tp_days = floor<days>(tp);
    year_month_day ymd = tp_days;
    hh_mm_ss hms{floor<milliseconds>(tp - tp_days)};
    switch (dp)
    {
    case DatePrecision::YEAR:
        return int{ymd.year()};
    case DatePrecision::MONTH:
        return unsigned{ymd.month()};
    case DatePrecision::DAY:
        return unsigned{ymd.day()};
    case DatePrecision::HOUR:
        return hms.hours().count();
    case DatePrecision::MINUTE:
        return hms.minutes().count();
    case DatePrecision::SECOND:
        return hms.seconds().count();
    case DatePrecision::MILLI:
        return hms.subseconds().count();
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    long long et = 1693322440062;
    std::chrono::milliseconds ms{ et };
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> tp(ms);

    cout << tp << '\n';
    cout << getTimeUnit(tp, DatePrecision::YEAR) << '\n';
    cout << getTimeUnit(tp, DatePrecision::MONTH) << '\n';
    cout << getTimeUnit(tp, DatePrecision::DAY) << '\n';
    cout << getTimeUnit(tp, DatePrecision::HOUR) << '\n';
    cout << getTimeUnit(tp, DatePrecision::MINUTE) << '\n';
    cout << getTimeUnit(tp, DatePrecision::SECOND) << '\n';
    cout << getTimeUnit(tp, DatePrecision::MILLI) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2023-08-29 15:20:40.062000
2023
8
29
15
20
40
62
```

Explanation:

You need to switch on each desired field for the proper syntax to extract it from the `time_point`.  Note that `std::chrono::time_point` is a template, not a type.  I presumed you meant `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` (or equivalently `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>`) in the `getTimeUnit` signature.

Also note that `time_point`s based on `system_clock` have the semantics of UTC, not local time.

For the "date fields", first truncate the `time_point` to `days` precision with `floor<days>`, and then convert that to a `year_month_day`.  The `year_month_day` type has getters for `year`, `month` and `day`, which subsequently have explicit conversions to integral types.

For the "time of day fields", subtract the day-precision `time_point` from the original to get the time of day as a duration.  Then the type `hh_mm_ss` transforms that `duration` into a `{hours, minutes, seconds, subseconds}` data structure with getters for each field.

If you don't have the C++20 chrono bits available to you, you can still use this code by taking advantage of my [free, open-source, header-only C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Just add `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;` in appropriate places, and the rest of the syntax is the same.  This will obviously easily port to C++20 when you are able to migrate to it.

Disclaimer: I've thrown this together, and it can probably be refactored to be a little bit neater.  But hopefully this will get you started.

---

### Now with time zones

> Using this a bit more, it is indeed problematic that this not aware of time zones (or is using the wrong one, I'm UTC+1). Is there any quick fix to consider these?

There's a few ways to interpret this, but I *think* I know what you mean. :-)

1. The input is UTC (Unix Time) and you want the output in the current local time zone.
2. The input is a local time point and you want the output units in UTC.
3. The input is a local time point and you want the output units in local time.

The third is trivial, and won't change the results.  Though to be consistent, the input should use `local_time` instead of `sys_time` as the input (e.g. `std::chrono::local_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>` as the first parameter).

The second would be somewhat unusual, but is certainly easy.  It would be only a minor modification of the first choice (which I'm assuming you want).

I'm assuming you mean the first.  Here is a slight modification of my original answer that outputs the units in a time zone of your choosing, and defaults to your computer's local time zone:

```
int
getTimeUnit(const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp_utc,
            const DatePrecision dp,
            const std::chrono::time_zone* tz = std::chrono::current_zone())
{ 
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto tp_local = tz->to_local(tp_utc);
    auto tp_days = floor<days>(tp_local);
    year_month_day ymd{tp_days};
    hh_mm_ss hms{floor<milliseconds>(tp_local - tp_days)};
    switch (dp)
    {
    case DatePrecision::YEAR:
        return int{ymd.year()};
    case DatePrecision::MONTH:
        return unsigned{ymd.month()};
    case DatePrecision::DAY:
        return unsigned{ymd.day()};
    case DatePrecision::HOUR:
        return hms.hours().count();
    case DatePrecision::MINUTE:
        return hms.minutes().count();
    case DatePrecision::SECOND:
        return hms.seconds().count();
    case DatePrecision::MILLI:
        return hms.subseconds().count();
    }
}
```

Besides some variable renaming (for clarity), there's really only two changes:

1. You first have to convert the input UTC time point to a local time point with `auto tp_local = tz->to_local(tp_utc);`.
2. The conversion from the `days`-precision `time_point` to `year_month_day` is now an explicit conversion as opposed to an implicit one:  `year_month_day ymd{tp_days};`.  Explicit conversion syntax would have also worked in the original code.

Everything else is exactly the same, even including how you use it:

```
int h = getTimeUnit(tp, DatePrecision::HOUR);
```

However if you would like to specify the time zone instead of get the local one, that can be done like this:

```
int h = getTimeUnit(tp, DatePrecision::HOUR,
                    std::chrono::locate_zone("America/New_York"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply! I realize that casting to int is not ideal, especially as the next step is to do calculations (e.g. 2023-12-31 + 2 months = 2024-02-28). So I absolutely want to stick to the `chrono` type system as much as possible. I embarrassed to admit that I really struggle with `templates`, so I'm still confused about the right syntax in `chrono`, especially when I also want to consider time zones and leap years.

Comment: Using this a bit more, it is indeed problematic that this not aware of time zones (or is using the wrong one, I'm UTC+1). Is there any quick fix to consider these?

Comment: Updated answer to be time zone aware.

Comment: Again, thank you soo much for your effort and valuable time, it is very much appreciated! I will need some time to implement this, but just fyi, here is the scenario: The user may, depending on the setting, remove the hour/minute/second/millisecond information on the UI (Javascript `Date`) but they still see the same date. If I understand how times and time zones work, this means that while the UI shows the same day, C++ may actually interpret the number as different days if the used time zone is not also considered. But again, this is perfect and I will have to experiment with this further.